# Are there any downsides to switching off Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, docker, hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I like to be able to use VirtualBox as I am doing a couple of courses that require it, but I also want to use WSL2 (and I'd quite like to use Docker, too).

I don't think VBox works with Hyper-V enabled, so it seems I'd need to switch it on & off whenever needed.

Are there any downsides to switching it on/off?

Comment: The current version of Docker and VirtualBox (6.1) both absolutely support Hyper-V provided your running the current version of Windows 10 (20H2).  **WSL2 absolutely does not require Hyper-V to be enabled** Hyper-V does not come enabled on any edition of Windows by default.  So it likely isn’t enabled currently unless you enabled it.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that docker desktop can run with a WSL2 backend, so if WSL2 doesn't require hyper-V (I thought that it did) then I suppose it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I like to be able to use VirtualBox as I am doing a couple of courses that require it, but I also want to use WSL2 (and I'd quite like to use docker, too). I don't think VBox works with hyper-v enabled, so it seems I'd need to switch it on & off whenever needed.

The current version of Docker and VirtualBox (6.1) both absolutely support Hyper-V provided your running the current version of Windows 10 (20H2). WSL2 absolutely does not require Hyper-V to be enabled Hyper-V does not come enabled on any edition of Windows by default. So it likely isn’t enabled currently unless you enabled it.

> Are there any downsides to switching this on/off?

The only notable downside would be the fact that Hyper-V isn’t enabled.  You might want to make sure it’s actually currently enabled, since by default, Hyper-V isn’t enabled on any version of Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

As [the doc](http://Use%20Hyper-V%20paravirtualization%20with%20VirtualBox%206) states at the beginning (the doc also shows how to use Hyper-V paravirtualization with VirtualBox 6):

> Since version 6.0, VirtualBox is able to use the Hyper-V API to
> coexist next to Hyper-V. But, performance will be worse and it does
> not work with all versions of Windows 10 (versions 1079 and earlier of Windows 10 are not supported).

You can use **a multi-boot to boot or not with Hyper-V** (if you want) so you don't have to uninstall and reinstall Hyper-V every time.

Here are some steps to use multi-boot for you to check:
https://us.informatiweb.net/tutorials/it/virtualization/hyper-v-coexistence-with-virtualbox-or-vmware-workstation.html#solve-problem-with-multi-boot